# Compact sets in a metric space

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

On a non finite metric space, every compact can be finite?
I guess it is false, but I don't know how can one prove it, I already know that at most the space has finite compact sets, but I have not a contradiction yet.

Comment: Are you asking: is every compact subset of an infinite metric space necessarily finite?

Comment: @DavidMitra Since every finite subset of a metric space is compact, I doubt that that is the question.

Comment: yes, in fact this is the right question.

Comment: Andreas' answer below shows there is an infinite metric space in which every compact set is finite.  But it's not true for general spaces. Compact sets need not be finite. Take the unit interval in $\Bbb R$, for example.

Comment: yes, in fact this is the right question. I have been trying to show  this is false by contradiction, is why i say that I only have, if this is true i only get finite compacts, that are finite themself.

Answer (score 2):

Take any infinite set and define a metric on it by declaring the distance between any two distinct points to be $1$.  Then the only compact subsets of this (discrete) space are the finite sets.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the positive integers with the inherited topology from the reals. This is the simplest example I can think of.

Comment: Same for me, +1.